# How to create multiple sub-plots in python using for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

How to generate separate plots for each year from 2004 to 2015, using python loop?

Currently I am repeating the code with each year, and its too tedious

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,15), dpi= 80)
calmap.yearplot(df_raw1['2004']['TEU'], cmap='YlGn', fillcolor='grey',
                linewidth=0) # Plot for year 2004

plt.figure(figsize=(30,15), dpi= 80)
calmap.yearplot(df_raw1['2005']['TEU'], cmap='YlGn', fillcolor='grey',
                linewidth=0) # Plot for year 2005

plt.figure(figsize=(30,15), dpi= 80)
calmap.yearplot(df_raw1['2005']['TEU'], cmap='YlGn', fillcolor='grey',
                linewidth=0) # Plot for year 2006

plt.figure(figsize=(30,15), dpi= 80)
calmap.yearplot(df_raw1['2007']['TEU'], cmap='YlGn', fillcolor='grey',
                linewidth=0) # Plot for year 2007

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please provide `df_raw1`?

Comment: The 'year' portion is set as index of a date column 'Date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
years = ['2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009','2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']

for i in range(len(years)):
    plt.figure(figsize=(30,15), dpi= 80)
    calmap.yearplot(df_raw1[years[i]]['TEU'], cmap='YlGn', fillcolor='grey', linewidth=0) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Thank you.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as answer if possible. You are welcome.